# Pic18F67K22 Unable to set SPBRGH1

Tags: uart, pic, microchip

PIC1867K22 @ 64 Mhz with MPLAB 8.92.
Trying to set baud rate to 9600 and unable to get the `SPBRGH1` register to change its stuck on `0xC2`. Set ports `RC6`, `RC7` as needed or I/0. The UART sends and receives data but wrong baud. Using 16 byte baud rate

```
movlw   b'10010000' ;// UART RC.6 RF TX out
MOVWF   TRISC 




banksel TXSTA1 
movlw   b'10000100' ;// 9600 baud
movwf   TXSTA1 

bsf BAUDCON1,3  ;// 16 byte

bcf BAUDCON1,5  ;// Data NOT inverted (Rx)
bcf BAUDCON1,4  ;// Data NOY  inverted (Tx)

movlw   0x66        ;// 64 mhz      
movwf   SPBRG1

movlw   0x16
movwf   SPBRGH1     

movlw   b'10010000'
movwf   RCSTA1          ;//Enable Serial
```

Comment: Try first to set `RCSTA1` and then other registers.

Comment: It seems your problem may be simpler than I though. The numbers you are using for SPBRG1 and SPBRGH1 are the DECIMAL digits decorated as if they are a HEXADECDIMAL value. Try setting SPBRG1 to 0x06 and SPBRGH1 to 0x82.

Comment: You are correct 1666 was decimal. Turns out I did not need to use 16 byte baud. i used 103 dec and got it working. I tried to respond to this post but each time was knocked off. hopefully this one will post.

Answer (score 0):

The PIC18F67K22 has all of the Special Function Registers located in memory common to all banks.

I suspect that whatever your problem is, it may on be in the code you have yet posted.

This complete application will setup the UART and build with MPASM:

```
    list n=0,c=250      ; Make list file look pretty
    list r=dec          ; use decimal numbers as the default
;
;  Author   : Dan1138
;  Date     : 2021-APRIL-06
;  Target   : PIC18F67K22
;  IDE      : MPLAB v8.92
;  Compiler : MPASM
;                                                           PIC18F67K22
;             +---------------+            +---------------+            +---------------+            +---------------+
;          <> :  1 RE1        :         <> : 17 RF1/AN6    :         <> : 33 RC2/ECCP1  :         <> : 49 RD7        :
;          <> :  2 RE0        :     3v3 -> : 18 ENVREG     :         <> : 34 RC3/SCL1   :         <> : 50 RD6/SCL2   :
;          <> :  3 RG0/ECCP3  :     3v3 -> : 19 AVDD       :         <> : 35 RC4/SDA1   :         <> : 51 RD5/SDA2   :
;          <> :  4 RG1/AN19   :     GND -> : 20 AVSS       :         <> : 36 RC5        :         <> : 52 RD4        :
;          <> :  5 RG2/AN18   :         <> : 21 RA3/AN3    : IDC_PGD <> : 37 RB7/PGD    :         <> : 53 RD3        :
;          <> :  6 RG3/AN17   :         <> : 22 RA2/AN2    :     3v3 -> : 38 VDD        :         <> : 54 RD2        :
;  ICD_VPP -> :  7 RG5/MCLR   :         <> : 23 RA1/AN1    :         <> : 39 RA7/OSC1   :         <> : 55 RD1        :
;          <> :  8 RG4/AN16   :         <> : 24 RA0/AN0    :         <> : 30 RA6/OSC2   :      GND-> : 56 VSS        :
;      GND -> :  9 VSS        :     GND -> : 25 VSS        :     GND -> : 41 VSS        :      3v3-> : 57 VDD        :
;     10uF -> : 10 VCAP       :     3v3 -> : 26 VDD        : ICD_PGC <> : 42 RB6/PGC    :         <> : 58 RD0        :
;          <> : 11 RF7/AN5    :         <> : 27 RA5/AN4    :         <> : 43 RB5        :         <> : 59 RE7/ECCP2  :
;          <> : 12 RF6/AN11   :         <> : 28 RA4/T0CKI  :         <> : 44 RB4        :         <> : 60 RE6/CCP6   :
;          <> : 13 RF5/AN10   :         <> : 29 RC1/SOSCI  :         <> : 45 RB3        :         <> : 61 RE5/CCP7   :
;          <> : 14 RF4/AN9    :         <> : 30 RC0/SOSCO  :         <> : 46 RB2        :         <> : 62 RE4/CCP8   :
;          <> : 15 RF3/AN8    :         <> : 31 RC6/TX1    :         <> : 47 RB1/INT1   :         <> : 63 RE3/CCP9   :
;          <> : 16 RF2/AN7    :         <> : 32 RC7/RX1    :         <> : 48 RB0/INT0   :         <> : 64 RE2/CCP10  :
;             +---------------+            +---------------+            +---------------+            +---------------+
;                                                             TQFP-64

;
; Include definitions of the special function registers
;
#include "p18f67k22.inc"
;
; Initialize all of the configuration word bits
;
; CONFIG1L
  CONFIG  RETEN = ON                ; VREG Sleep Enable bit (Enabled)
  CONFIG  INTOSCSEL = HIGH          ; LF-INTOSC Low-power Enable bit (LF-INTOSC in High-power mode during Sleep)
  CONFIG  SOSCSEL = HIGH            ; SOSC Power Selection and mode Configuration bits (High Power SOSC circuit selected)
  CONFIG  XINST = OFF               ; Extended Instruction Set (Disabled)
    
; CONFIG1H    
  CONFIG  FOSC = INTIO2             ; Oscillator (Internal RC oscillator)
  CONFIG  PLLCFG = OFF              ; PLL x4 Enable bit (Disabled)
  CONFIG  FCMEN = OFF               ; Fail-Safe Clock Monitor (Disabled)
  CONFIG  IESO = OFF                ; Internal External Oscillator Switch Over Mode (Disabled)
    
; CONFIG2L    
  CONFIG  PWRTEN = OFF              ; Power Up Timer (Disabled)
  CONFIG  BOREN = OFF               ; Brown Out Detect (Disabled in hardware, SBOREN disabled)
  CONFIG  BORV = 3                  ; Brown-out Reset Voltage bits (1.8V)
  CONFIG  BORPWR = ZPBORMV          ; BORMV Power level (ZPBORMV instead of BORMV is selected)
    
; CONFIG2H    
  CONFIG  WDTEN = OFF               ; Watchdog Timer (WDT disabled in hardware; SWDTEN bit disabled)
  CONFIG  WDTPS = 1048576           ; Watchdog Postscaler (1:1048576)
    
; CONFIG3L    
  CONFIG  RTCOSC = SOSCREF          ; RTCC Clock Select (RTCC uses SOSC)
    
; CONFIG3H    
  CONFIG  CCP2MX = PORTC            ; CCP2 Mux (RC1)
  CONFIG  MSSPMSK = MSK7            ; MSSP address masking (7 Bit address masking mode)
  CONFIG  MCLRE = ON                ; Master Clear Enable (MCLR Enabled, RG5 Disabled)

; CONFIG4L
  CONFIG  STVREN = ON               ; Stack Overflow Reset (Enabled)
  CONFIG  BBSIZ = BB2K              ; Boot Block Size (2K word Boot Block size)
    
; CONFIG5L    
  CONFIG  CP0 = OFF                 ; Code Protect 00800-03FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP1 = OFF                 ; Code Protect 04000-07FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP2 = OFF                 ; Code Protect 08000-0BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP3 = OFF                 ; Code Protect 0C000-0FFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP4 = OFF                 ; Code Protect 10000-13FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP5 = OFF                 ; Code Protect 14000-17FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP6 = OFF                 ; Code Protect 18000-1BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CP7 = OFF                 ; Code Protect 1C000-1FFFF (Disabled)
    
; CONFIG5H    
  CONFIG  CPB = OFF                 ; Code Protect Boot (Disabled)
  CONFIG  CPD = OFF                 ; Data EE Read Protect (Disabled)
    
; CONFIG6L    
  CONFIG  WRT0 = OFF                ; Table Write Protect 00800-03FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT1 = OFF                ; Table Write Protect 04000-07FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT2 = OFF                ; Table Write Protect 08000-0BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT3 = OFF                ; Table Write Protect 0C000-0FFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT4 = OFF                ; Table Write Protect 10000-13FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT5 = OFF                ; Table Write Protect 14000-17FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT6 = OFF                ; Table Write Protect 18000-1BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRT7 = OFF                ; Table Write Protect 1C000-1FFFF (Disabled)
    
; CONFIG6H    
  CONFIG  WRTC = OFF                ; Config. Write Protect (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRTB = OFF                ; Table Write Protect Boot (Disabled)
  CONFIG  WRTD = OFF                ; Data EE Write Protect (Disabled)
    
; CONFIG7L    
  CONFIG  EBRT0 = OFF               ; Table Read Protect 00800-03FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT1 = OFF               ; Table Read Protect 04000-07FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT2 = OFF               ; Table Read Protect 08000-0BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT3 = OFF               ; Table Read Protect 0C000-0FFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT4 = OFF               ; Table Read Protect 10000-13FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT5 = OFF               ; Table Read Protect 14000-17FFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT6 = OFF               ; Table Read Protect 18000-1BFFF (Disabled)
  CONFIG  EBRT7 = OFF               ; Table Read Protect 1C000-1FFFF (Disabled)
    
; CONFIG7H    
  CONFIG  EBRTB = OFF               ; Table Read Protect Boot (Disabled)
;
; Define what we are going to setup as the system oscillator frequency
;
#define FSYS (64000000)
#define FCY  (FSYS/4)
;
; Reset vector
;
RES_VECT  CODE    0x0000            ; processor reset vector
    GOTO    START                   ; go to beginning of program
;
; High priority interrupt vector
;
ISR_HIGH_VECTOR code 0x00008
        goto    ISR_HIGH_HANDLER
;
ISR_LOW_DATA udata_acs
wreg_temp:   res 1
status_temp: res 1
pclath_temp: res 1
;
; Low priority interrupt handler
;
ISR_LOW_VECTOR code 0x00018
ISR_LOW_HANDLER:
        movwf   wreg_temp            ; save off current W register contents
        movf    STATUS,w             ; move status register into W register
        clrf    STATUS               ; force to bank zero
        movwf   status_temp          ; save off contents of STATUS register
        movf    PCLATH,W
        movwf   pclath_temp
        movlw   HIGH(ISR_LOW_HANDLER)
        movwf   PCLATH


; isr code can go here or be located as a called subroutine elsewhere


        movf    pclath_temp,W
        movwf   PCLATH
        movf    status_temp,w        ; retrieve copy of STATUS register
        movwf   STATUS               ; restore pre-isr STATUS register contents
        swapf   wreg_temp,f
        swapf   wreg_temp,w          ; restore pre-isr W register contents
        retfie                       ; return from interrupt
;
; High priority interrupt handler
;
ISR_HIGH_HANDLER:
        retfie  FAST
;
; Main application
;
MAIN_PROG CODE
;
; Turn off interrupts
; Make all GPIO pins digiatl outputs
;
START:
    clrf    INTCON
    movlw   0x70
    MOVWF   OSCCON
    clrf    OSCTUNE
    bsf     OSCTUNE,PLLEN
;
    clrf    ANCON0
    clrf    ANCON1
    clrf    ANCON2
;
    clrf    LATA
    clrf    LATB
    clrf    LATC
    clrf    LATD
    clrf    LATE
    clrf    LATF
    clrf    LATG

    clrf    TRISA
    clrf    TRISB
    clrf    TRISC
    clrf    TRISD
    clrf    TRISE
    clrf    TRISF
    clrf    TRISG
;
; Setup UART1
;
#define U1_BAUD 9600
#define U1_BRGH_VALUE 1
#define U1_BRG16_VALUE 1
;
; Compute the value for the UART1 baud rate registers
;
#if U1_BRG16_VALUE
    #if U1_BRGH_VALUE
        #define U1_BRGH_SCALE 1
    #else
        #define U1_BRGH_SCALE 4
    #endif
#else
    #if U1_BRGH_VALUE
        #define U1_BRGH_SCALE 4
    #else
        #define U1_BRGH_SCALE 16
    #endif
#endif

#define U1_SPBRG_VALUE (((FCY+(U1_BRGH_SCALE*U1_BAUD/2))/(U1_BRGH_SCALE*U1_BAUD))-1)

#if U1_BRG16_VALUE
    #if (U1_SPBRG_VALUE >> 16)
    error "Cannot set up UART1 for the FCY and BAUDRATE."
    #endif
#else
    #if (U1_SPBRG_VALUE >> 8)
    error "Cannot set up UART1 for the FCY and BAUDRATE."
    #endif
#endif
;
; Check if the real baud rate is within 2.5 percent of the require baud rate
;
#define REAL_BAUDRATE (FCY/(U1_BRGH_SCALE*(U1_SPBRG_VALUE+1)))
#if (REAL_BAUDRATE > (U1_BAUD+(U1_BAUD*25)/1000)) 
 error "UART baudrate error greater than 2.5 percent for the FCY and U1_BAUD."
#endif
#if (REAL_BAUDRATE < (U1_BAUD-(U1_BAUD*25)/1000))
 error "UART baudrate error greater than 2.5 percent for the FCY and U1_BAUD."
#endif
;
    bsf     LATC,LATC6      ; Set U1_TXD high
    bsf     TRISC,TRISC7    ; Set U1_RXD as digital input
    clrf    TXSTA1
    clrf    RCSTA1
    clrf    BAUDCON1
#if (U1_BRG16_VALUE)
    bsf     BAUDCON1,BRG16
#endif
#if (U1_BRGH_VALUE)
    bsf     TXSTA1,BRGH
#endif
#if (U1_BRG16_VALUE)
    movlw   HIGH(U1_SPBRG_VALUE)
    movwf   SPBRGH1
#endif
    movlw   LOW(U1_SPBRG_VALUE)
    movwf   SPBRG1
    bsf     TXSTA1,TXEN
    bsf     RCSTA1,CREN
    bsf     RCSTA1,SPEN
;
; Send a "Start" message
;
    movlw   0x0d
    call    U1_Putc
    movlw   0x0a
    call    U1_Putc
    movlw   'S'
    call    U1_Putc
    movlw   't'
    call    U1_Putc
    movlw   'a'
    call    U1_Putc
    movlw   'r'
    call    U1_Putc
    movlw   't'
    call    U1_Putc
    movlw   0x0d
    call    U1_Putc
    movlw   0x0a
    call    U1_Putc
;
; Application process loop
;
AppLoop:
    GOTO    AppLoop
;
; Send a character out UART
;
U1_Putc:
    btfss   TXSTA1,TRMT
    bra     U1_Putc
    movwf   TXREG1
    return
    END
```